# what could possible cause of having "this page has a redirect loop"?

Tags: php, yii

i added this script in a page whereby, it needs to redirect the page when the item is ought to be bought by the users

```
if($servertime >= $itemtime && $model->isActive()){
    header("Location: ". $redirectpage);
    exit();
}
```

the error only happens in the morning, i don't know what's causing the error, when i checked the error logs, i can only see a huge dump of yii that has this readable text saying

```
Unable to resolve request
```

any ideas ?

Comment: hmm is there a difference between military time and normal time?

Comment: Are $servertime and $itemtime both in epoch time? How is $redirectpage defined? Perhaps it is empty, it redirects on itself and hits the same conditional repeatedly?

Comment: `$servertime = date('F d,Y G:i:s',time());`   `$itemtime = $timedate. " " .$slot[$model->SBTIMESLOT].":".$timesecs;`   where in, $slot[$model->SBTIMESLOT] is in 24 hour format of the hours...and then $timedate is just date('F d,Y') and $timesecs is just date('i:s');

Comment: the $redirectpage is not empty it's like `Yii::app()->createUrl('blahblahblah')` ....the redirection works fun, but when i checked yesterday morning and today, the redirection doesn't work , am seeing that redirection loop error page

Comment: What happens if you do `if (true) { header("Location: ". $redirectpage); exit(); }` ? Do you get the same redirect loop?

Comment: By the way, in Yii you can always do [`Yii::app()->getController()->redirect(...)`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail), or if you're in a controller just `$this->redirect(...)`.

Comment: as said above, you should not use `header("Location")` to redirect in Yii. You need to show us way more code, what is $itemtime ? what it $servertime ? what is $redirectpage ?